Diff working tree of currently open tab with HEAD without going to commit pane
When I am working on a file that is modified, and I want to view the changes, currently I go to the commit pane, select the file in question, and do a Ctrl + D to view changes of the working tree compared to HEAD -- basically what you get with:
git diff <filename>

This requires multiple steps for what has to be one of the most common operations out there; is there an IntelliJ action I can map to a hotkey that does this comparison for the currently open file?

Found this action:
Compare with the same Repository version
